# Why is my Tamron 70-300mm lens limited to DX framing on Nikon D750?

Tags: lens, nikon, tamron, dx

I'm trying all of my lenses on my newly acquired D750.

Among the lenses there is a Tamron 70-300 LD Di zoom lens. Everything works as expected, except one thing: the D750 limits the frame-size to DX (indicated in the viewer and on the  screen with the info-view turned on).

Using the other lenses I can switch between Full and DX.

Why is the selection limited for the 70-300mm lens?

Comment: 3rd party lenses are reverse engineered to work on Nikon bodies and sometimes new bodies are not fully compatible with older 3rd party lenses.  Does the lens auto focus while in liveview? (this has also been a problem in the past)

Comment: Liveview AF still doesn't work with this lens. AF during shooting stops randomly to work. This was already the case on my D90 - but less often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have "Auto Dx crop" enabled? If so, try disabling the "Auto DX crop" setting. **Photo Shooting Menu > Image area > Choose image area > Auto DX crop**. Change **Auto DX crop** to **Off** (if it's On).

You can still manually change the sensor area between Full and DX, and even assign that setting to a quick menu setting so it is easier to access.

As Mike Sowsun commented to your question, 3rd party lensmakers have to reverse-engineer the signals through the lens mount. Sometimes, new bodies are different enough (perhaps electrical signal differences such as voltage levels, switching thresholds, timing, etc.) that the lenses that existed before the new bodies came out unfortunately made wrong, or at least incomplete, assumptions about how to interface the camera system. While not exactly *rampant*, the problem you're experiencing pops up from time to time.

See also: [D3 + Tamron 70-300 f4-5.6 (NOT VC) FX lens but D3 treats as DX!](http://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/2306762) (dpreview.com)